# Is this question off-topic because of being a copy/paste of another homework assignment?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, close-reasons, homework

For this question:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/95474/circular-queue-program

one of the answers noted that the code in the question appears to be copy/pasted from [this homework assignment](http://pastebin.com/QnvHtTr0).

Should the question therefore be closed as off-topic?

Clarification: The code does not appear to be written by the question asker.  The homework was basically: "How can you make this code better in these three places" and the OP pasted that code as his question and asked about those three places.

Edit: I found a couple of other links to the code.  One is from [coursehero.com](https://www.coursehero.com/file/8200844/prSol113/) and one is from [highered.mheducation.com](http://highered.mheducation.com/sites/dl/free/0073047023/580827/chapter11Projects.doc).

Comment: I don't see anything that indicates it wasn't the OP's. What makes you think this?

Comment: @RubberDuck Did you read the pastebin link?

Comment: Got it. Yes. Off topic. We're not here to do anyone's homework for them. The technical reason would be it's not OP's code.

Comment: Glad to see this got resolved, and now I know that these are considered off topic

Comment: Funny how the code is now the *inelegant standard*. I wouldn't be surprised if this becomes a yearly/semester-ly occurrence or something...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[homework](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) questions are not off topic in and of themselves.  However, when reviewing homework assignments, there are certain guidelines to be followed - mainly, not giving the solution directly.

Given the clarification, questions with code not written or maintained by the asker are off topic, and I don't think homework questions with given code to work from counts as maintaining the code.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a copy paste of someone else's material and is off-topic by means of "not your code"